# how to creating new rows in pandas by subtreacing a column each time?

Tags: python, pandas

i want to create a new dataframe like this

this is my data

```
queue_id     agent_id login_duration   Hour DayofWeek   logout_reason_id
1   12  1593    2.280833    0   Tue 11.0
2   12  1593    2.280278    0   Tue 11.0
3   12  1593    2.279722    0   Tue 11.0
4   13  1593    2.279444    0   Tue 11.0
5   13  1593    2.279167    0   Tue 11.0
```

i want this:

```
queue_id     agent_id login_duration   Hour Day of Week logout_reason_id
1   12  1593    2.280833    0   Tue 11.0
2   12  1593    1.280833    1   Tue 11.0
3   12  1593    0.280833    2   Tue 11.0
4   12  1593    2.280278    0   Tue 11.0
5   12  1593    1.280278    1   Tue 11.0
6   12  1593    0.280278    2   Tue 11.0
```

Comment: how do you go from one queue id to the other?

Comment: Hey Taleb, can you give us more detail, what informs the count on login_duration? does anything above `2 = 0` `1=1` and `0-1 = 2`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want to do is the following: for each row in the original data frame, if `login_duration > 1` then create a new row with the same entries except `login_duration += -1` and `hour += 1`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I'm right about what you're trying to do, here's a solution I think should work

```
li = []

for i in df.index:
    temp = int(np.floor(df.loc[i,'login_duration']))
    temp_df = df[i:i+1]
    for j in range(1, temp+1):
        temp_df = temp_df.append(df[i:i+1], ignore_index=True)
        temp_df.loc[j, 'login_duration'] += -j
        temp_df.loc[j, 'Hour'] += j
    li.append(temp_df)

df = li[0]
for d in li[1:]:
    df = df.append(d, ignore_index=True)
```

I am sure it's far from the best solution, but I think it should work. It works for the data you gave.